# Can't get steam running on a ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, steam

i'm on ubuntu 14.04 and am having problems with getting steam to run. I'm running on an i5 with intel HD integrated graphics.

originally, an easily-googleable problem....was missing libc package.

i installed these three packages, as per isntructions in a forum post:

- libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
- libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
- libc6:i386

and it miraculously worked...it updated steam, and i then reboot the system.

however, when i try to run steam, i get the message "openGL GLX not supported on this display". 
i installed the intel driver at the bottom of https://01.org/linuxgraphics/

as i have an intel chip and every single forum post i've looked up revolves around nvidia drivers, so i know that's where i messed up...i assume mesa-glx is nvidia-related or all three of the packages are nvidia-related...and googling didn't seem to get past all the nvidia-related posts.

Where did i err?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the legacy drivers of your graphic car, in this case seems to be nvidia, in those package is included the OpenGl and all the stuff.

You will need to install the headers firsts:

sudo apt-get install dist-upgrade

then download the drivers from the original website, make the file with extension .run executable and run it with privileges of root or sudoer.

Comment: so sorry. i erased the top line that said i had an intel integrated chip.  i think i followed a tutorial that was nvidia specific which is how i got even this far...but to no avail! i also installed the intel driver at the bottom of https://01.org/linuxgraphics/

Comment: Intel supports linux, you can download the legacy drivers.